Network Manager is not working in Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS
I tried everything like “sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
” and tried with live usb boot (like : sudo fdisk -l
and sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /mnt and after sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
and run sudo chroot /mnt
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall network-manager
exit
after sudo umount /mnt/dev
sudo umount /mnt/proc
sudo umount /mnt/sys
sudo umount /mnt
sudo reboot
)
but sitll not working for me. nmcli d  show “Unmangaed” I edited conf file “[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=true
” but still not work for me. Please help me in this regard.
enter image description here
